# How to write array to plist using Swift?

Tags: swift, collections, plist

What I actually needed at the begining of my work, was to make a plist file with some properties inside. Because, as I have found (maybe I haven't found and you know a better solution, than let me know), there is no such a thing as simple programmatical plist file creation, I have written a test plist file, looked what is inside and using a simple file creator class, wrote such a thing:

```
class PlistCreator{
init(nameOfFile : String){
    var path = "\(NSHomeDirectory())/Documents/XCODE/getPDBInfo/DATA_PDB/cifGraphRed/\(nameOfFile).plist"

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let text = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">\n\t<plist version=\"1.0\">\n\t\t<dict><key>017</key>\n<dict\n<key>O26</key>\n<dict>\n<key>Atoms</key>\n<key>AtomsRed</key>\n<key>Connections</key>\n<array/>\n<key>Ring</key>\n<array/>\n</dict>\n</dict>\n</dict>\n</plist>"
    let dataText = (text as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    fileManager.createFileAtPath(path, contents: dataText, attributes: nil)

}

}
```

I also needed to make a file programatically, because I need some thousands of such plist files, which should be named differently.
As you can see file contains some pre-arrays (they are currently empty), but I want to add information to them. How do I add certain data to certain collections, specifying what and where I should add?
Just in case, here is the empty file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"       "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>017</key>
<dict>
    <key>O26</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AtomsList</key>
        <array/>
        <key>Connections</key>
        <array/>
        <key>Ring</key>
        <array/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Array is not in the project, it is outside, like:

```
User/Documents/Files/Data/plist#2587.plist
```

I can see now two solutions: 1) There must be some way to use all these nested pathes and to write data inside chosen collections;
2) I should work with the plist as I work with any text file, in such a case there should be a way to write between chosen lines of file.

Comment: The NSDictionary and NSArray methods `writeToFile()` create plist files, there is no need to have your own plist writing code. And there is NSPropertyListSerialization.

Comment: The thing is that I also need to modify names of inner contents - e.g. <key>O26</key> has to be actually something like <key>\(vertexName)</key> and there is also a need in lots of subarrays, i.e. nested arrays